# How do I get this DIV which has fixed position set by Javascript to stay within the containing DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebisumartin/n1pkp6wy/1/) where I am trying to make a DIV stay fixed vertically in the viewport as the user scrolls, but stay under a header.

However, the fixed DIV, with the green border, pops over to the right edge of the viewport when you scroll down to the point where the Javascript kicks in.

How do I constrain the green DIV so that it stays within the red bordered containing DIV? Ideally its horizontal position would stay fixed relative to the right edge of the container.

CSS:

```
header {
   width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    border: purple thin solid;
}
#container {
    border: thin solid red;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:30em;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#staticRight {
    border: green thin solid;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    margin: 2em 0 0 0;
    width: 120px;
    height:600px;
    font-size: .82em;
    line-height:2em;
}
article {
    border: blue thin solid;
    max-width: 20em;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var elementPosition = $('#staticRight').offset();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
        $('#staticRight').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');

    } else {
        $('#staticRight').css('position', 'static');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Giving `right` also to your `staticRight` div

```
$('#staticRight').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('right','20px');
```

Instead

```
$('#staticRight').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/8hs9t5wx/)**

Comment: Thank you for this response, but when I look at your JSFiddle, I don't see any behaviour different from my original.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an element to fixed, it gets out of the flow and hence setting the parent to relative would'nt matter. The fixed div gets positioned at the desired coordinates relative to the browser window. So if you can calculate the left poition from the browser, just add it to your `$(window).scroll` when you change it to fixed. Your code should look like this-

`<div id="staticRight" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 70%;"></div>`

Comment: Thank you for this response. Because the layout is responsive and fluid, I don't know if I can rely on a calculation of the left position. However, I do not need for the DIV to use fixed position. If there were other ways of making the div scroll with the user, whether with Javascript or anything else, I am open to any approach.

Comment: Well if its responsive, the simplest I can think of is adding right/left in the all your media query break points. like -@media screen and (min-width:767px) {
 #staticRight {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20%;
 }
}